# RandomAccessFile equivalent for directory/folder

Tags: java, directory, randomaccessfile

I have searched web and StackOverflow but did not find anything that would answer this specifically, I found answers like one cannot use `RandomAccessFile()` for reading a folder - OK, but is there something similar?

I have a piece of a code that originally read from a special type of a file using RandomAcessFile(), but as I have changed a lot of things in the content of that file by extracting them to a folder but there is no way how to pack them back to the original format (it can be extracted with a technique but there is no technique for packing it back) I need to now read it as a directory instead of a file. My problem is that there is a huge amount of classes made around it using `RandomAccessFile()` output so changing it all just because of this would be a "no-go".

Therefore my question is: what is - if any at all - some kind of equivalent that would output/return something like `RandomAccessFile()` output but for a directry/folder?

Specifically I would only need to update/change/fix that `file` variable in this part of the code:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(lifFile, "r");

long positionOffset = 0;

LIFFile rootFile = parseLIFFile(file, positionOffset);
LIFReader reader = new LIFReader(file, lifFile, rootFile, positionOffset);

return reader;
```

Can anyone tell/help how to do something like that?

**EDIT:**
Just a clarification: that special "original" file actually hold quantum of other files like images, 3D geometries, xml files in separate directories...

**EDIT 2:** So I have already solved it by creating completely new constructor (derivated form the original code) as suggested below - thanx for your thoughts, guys.

Comment: You should have made a `LIFReader(File f)` constructor, and it would be a lot easier. Now you have logic outside of it, so you've lost encapsulation and you'll have a harder time to do your change. This question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Kayaman ah, can't be done - as I said: all the other classses depending exactly on RandomAccessFile() output from this 1st "main" method, so I would end up exactly at the same stuff I am trying to avoid = creating all the methods in all classes anew with changed logic which I do not want to do (it actually is 3rd party class for reading that special file type so i want to avoid - beside other things - some unintentional breaking of some internal code logic I may not know about)

Comment: Yup, that's why you gotta design upfront so you don't run into these situations. There's no magical `RandomAccessDirectory` that would help you here. Refactor and don't make the same mistake again (or forget the whole thing).

Comment: @Kayaman once again - **IT IS NOT MY CLASS, it is 3rd party** so it was not my "mistake" or anyone else mistake as normally it is a file that needs to be read not a directory...

Comment: So you're using a library that reads files, and you decided to convert your files into directories and now you're complaining that the library doesn't work anymore? How on earth did you think that would work? You're right, there was no mistake here. Only a ridiculous idea on your part to convert the files to directories.

Comment: @Kayaman :-D ah man, maybe it's my english or we do not understand each other here at all: I am not complaining about anything, see: that file holds quantum of other files in directories like Decorations, 3D geometries, Color definitions etc. Normally one have to use only those predefined in that special file containing them, but by extracting that file one can change most of the stuff to his needs, so I did and now I need to update the code the way it would also be able  to read stuff inside that directory (which is actually just extracted special file) - hope this clarifies it a bit more

Comment: But if I understood you, the library expects a file as input. So unless you modify the library to read directories, or come up with a way to convert your directories back to the file, there's no way to do what you want. It also sounds strange that you can extract the file, but not repack it. What kind of weird one way decompression is that?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, that is correct..and exactly for that reason I am trying to find/ask first other skilled JAVA programmers if there is some easier way how to do it as I saw someone already did that before (but he is reluctant to tell how), thus being said maybe you are really right that there is no other way for me only to create new constructor but I want to be 100% sure before I go that way, you know - it is LIFextractor, you can extract but not pack it back, unfortunatelly [link](http://www.rockraidersunited.com/topic/3764-lego-digital-designer-lif-extractor/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, initially you had a file that represented a bundle of resources - and library you keep referring to had some trick to extract only a specific resource from that file. Since the only actual way of doing that is by giving an offset address, the library knows offsets inside the file, or it knows where to look for them in a given file.

Comment: The above means that if you only satisfied with RandomAccessFile, then you have to extend the `RandomAccessFile` in such way that it will now represent a collection of `RandomAccessFile`s, and will process given offset to find which exactly of the underlying files the offset refers to. At which point it will morph the given offset to a equivalent offset with respect to the underlying file, and query read/write operation with that computed offset. I myself would rather find a way to pack everything back the way it was, but if you really want, this is about the only path I see for you.

Comment: There are also a ton of ways the above can go wrong: you'd ideally also roll your own `FileChannel` with described seeking semantics. But `getChannel()` method is final on `RandomAccessFile`, which means this is impossible, meaning certain uses of your extended file may not work and/or lead to hard to discover bugs.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thank you for your thoughts...actually I think Kayaman was right after all (unfortunatelly) and I have to make new constructor with all the methods in respective classes as a while ago original author of the LIB answered me "in between lines" that I need to go that way...ah, nevermind, long creative process ahead - thank you guys for your thoughts, appreciated! ;-)

Comment: Actually, looking at code you attached, what's a `LIFFile`? Is it the thing that gives offsets? Because if it is, then we may be in luck somewhat with respect to at least knowing which offsets we will be looking for. Although I'd personally suggest that you maybe instead go for higher level of abstraction and detach all relevant code from `File` or `RandomAccessFile` altogether.

Comment: Sure, I've created a chat room [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139592/randomaccessfile-equivalent-for-directory-folder)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sorry i do not have 20 reputations so I cannot talk there :-(

Comment: See in [Q'n'A](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation): if you associate your Stackoverflow account with another account on some other Stack Exchange site, it should allow you to talk in chat since that gives +100 rep.

Comment: So if I understood it right I do have **3 accounts under my profile** (Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, LEGO® Answers) - is that what you mean? Then why do **I still have only 8 reputation points** - shouldn't I already have 308?